# Failed to import gradle

Tags: android, android-studio

I am brand new to android studio. Just downloaded it on my MacBook pro. Every time I try and create a new project I get the error in the following screenshot:

[image]

Anyone know whats going wrong here?

Comment: Wich version of OSX are you running? By the way, have you uploaded Android-Studio to the latest release? On windows, it uses gradle 1.7

Comment: @PaoloM Mac OS 10.8.4, I literally just downloaded android studio today so I assume its the latest release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you're running the latest version (0.2.6) of android-studio, via the menu Help -> About. If not, update via Help -> Check for update and see whether the problem persists.

Comment: Sure enough it was out of date. Thanks.